# How to remove this kind of switch case?

Tags: c++

I want to universalize a bulk of memory, which maybe loaded from a binary file, and the message id is known, i need to create the new instance for each memory chunk. What is the best way to do this?

The current situation is i need to add each new added message type to the following switch case.

```
struct Message1;
struct Message2;

void UnSerialize(int messageId, void* data) {
    switch (messageId) {
    case MESSAGE1:
        Message1* m1 = new Message1;
        std::memcpy(m1, data, sizeof(Message1));
        m1.dump();
        delete m1;
        break;
    case MESSAGE2:
        Message2* m2 = new Message2;
        std::memcpy(m2, data, sizeof(MESSAGE2));
        m2.dump();
        delete m2;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown Message Type.";
        break;
    }
}
```

can i wrote something like below in C++? Is it possible without C++11 and boost?

```
MessageTypeList tl;
tl.append(Message1);
tl.append(Message2);
void UnSerialize(MessageTypeList tl, int messageId, void* data) {
{
    foreach( type t : tl ) {
        if (t::id == MessageId) {
            t instance = new t;
            memcpy(t, data, sizeof(t));
            instance.dump();
            delete instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your hypothetical `UnSerialize` is equivalent to `void UnSerialize(MessageTypeList tl, int messageId, void* data) {}`. It has no side effects, beyond leaking memory. For that matter, so was the original `void UnSerialize(int messageId, void* data)`. What is supposed to happen to all that allocated memory?

Comment: What happens to your message after it is created in the switch statement? If you are just doing a memcpy, why does the type of message matter? (memcpy of class can be very bad).

Comment: Your code is invalid, `memcpy` is copying the size of a pointer. `new Message1;` doesn't work for incomplete types either. You use dynamic allocation for apparently no reason.

Comment: it would help to show examples of `Message1` etc.

Comment: In the `foreach`, are you looking for a way to iterate over a list of all classes that are derived from `MessageTypeList`? You cannot get that kind of information programmatically in C++, you need to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: Why the calls to new and delete?  You can simply allocate your Message objects on the stack, which will be more efficient and avoid any chance of a memory leak.  (You'll probably need to put curly braces around the case's contents)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you want to do but if you just want to call a `Dump` function from `Message1` or `Message2` struct, you can do the following:

```
struct BaseMessge
{
    virtual void Dump() = 0;
};
struct Message1 : public BaseMessage
{
    void Dump()
    {
        //Your code
    }
};
struct Message2 : public BaseMessage
{
    void Dump()
    {
        //Your code
    }
};

void UnSerialize(BaseMessage *Message)
{
    Message->Dump();
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would solve the problem since `UnSerialize` actually receives an integer arbitrarily mapped to some types and a pointer to an array of bytes. That array of bytes, given the function name and the need of an integer parameter, probably cannot have the a vtable pointer properly set, so virtual function calls will not work.

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways to express the list of pairs (type, id) and implement any behavior you want for each type or id. However, I think the the switch is still a very good approach - in any approach, you have to list all types soomehow - but let the code inside each case to be a template function.

```
template <class T>
void UnSerialize(void* data) {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,
                  "Message class is not trivally copyable");
    T message;
    memcpy(&message, data, sizeof(T));
    message.dump();
}

void UnSerialize(int messageId, void* data) {
    switch (messageId) {
    case MESSAGE1:
        UnSerialize<Message1>(data);
        break;
    case MESSAGE2:
        UnSerialize<Message2>(data);
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown Message Type.";
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I've suggested a different implementation for the code inside each case:

- No dynamic allocation, the message is allocated in a variable local to the function.
- Added a static assert that `memcpy` will work as expected.

Another approach, to avoid the `switch` at all, is to build an array of pairs of ID and instance of a helper class with a virtual method. Each instance would be from a derived template class that implement that virtual method with the code that would be in the case. Then, you just have to build that array statically (I suggest using `std::unique_ptr` to hold the pointer to the helper class).

Note that writing that array is very similar to writing the `switch` and just make your code harder to read.

Comment: What about single line of code in UnSerialize function? `((T*)data)->dump();`

Comment: @Quest, that should work on the majority of applications, but some care must be taken to ensure `data` is properly aligned for every `T`.